# How to make same axis range for numeric attributes and different axis range for ordinal group

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have visualized a parallel coordinates in d3 and the first axis represents names so it is an ordinal value, while other axis represent numbers. Just like this example http://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/4020926

but I want to have instead of `.domain(dimensions.map(function(d) { return d.name; }))` for the numeric attributes I want to have same axis range for each group `domain( [0,8] )` but I can't do it because then I loose the first ordinal axis. Any idea on how both could be mixed together?

EDIT:

```
d3.csv("cars.small.csv", function(data) {
  dimensions.forEach(function(dimension) {
    dimension.scale.domain(dimension.type === "number"
        ? d3.extent(data, function(d) { return +d[dimension.name]; })
        : data.map(function(d) { return d[dimension.name]; });
  });
```

in here I have to make the axis range go the same through all the other axis.

Comment: Could you add more of your code to address your specific problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing to this does the job:

```
d3.csv("cars.small.csv", function(data) {
  dimensions.forEach(function(dimension) {
    dimension.scale.domain(dimension.type === "number"
        ? ( [0,8] )
        : data.map(function(d) { return d[dimension.name]; });
  });
```